# Como puedo hacer una consulta a 2 bases diferente diferentes utilizando sqlsrv_query

Tags: php, sql-server, script, sqlsrv

Quiero obtener los datos de una tabla y agregarlos a otra tabla con la misma estructura utilizando un script php para luego hacer un cron. Pero no consigo establecer conexion con ambas bdd.

```
<?php

 $serverName = "IP1"; 
 $database2 = "DEMO";
 $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"DEMO", "UID"=>"demo", "PWD"=>"demo");

 $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo );

 if( $conn === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
 }
 else
 {
   echo 'Conexion Establecida';
 }




 $serverName = "IP2"; 
 $database2 = "PRUEBAS";
 $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"PRUEBAS", "UID"=>"prueba", "PWD"=>"prueba");

 $conn2 = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo );

 if( $conn === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
 }
 else
 {
   echo 'Conexion Establecida';
 }


 $sql = "Select * INTO [DEMO].[dbo].[ALERGIAS] FROM [PRUEBAS].[dbo].[ALERGIAS]";

 $params = array();
 $options =  array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );
 $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql , $params, $options );

 $row_count = sqlsrv_num_rows( $stmt );



if ($row_count === false)
   echo "Error al obtener datos.";
else
   echo "bien";


while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt) ) {
      print json_encode($row);
}

sqlsrv_close($conn);

?>
```

No se como tengo que pasarle al sqlsrv_query ambas conexiones para poder hacer la consulta.
A parte serian varias tablas y necesitaria poner un begin y un end por si falla alguna no lo haga.

Comment: No entiendo mucho tu problema. Si se trata de consultar tablas independientes en dos bases de datos, puedes hacerlo perfectamente, conectado a ambas DB y pasando en parámetro a cada consulta la conexión que le corresponda. Luego obtienes cada resultado en variables y lo usas. Un error que veo en tu código es que usas `$conn` para consultas en las que deberías usar `$conn2`.  Si, como dices, son varias consultas, lo más simple sería programar alguna SP en la base de datos que haga todas las consultas, controle todo y te devuelva los resultados.

Comment: Mi problema es como puedo ejecutar la consulta haciendo referencia a 2 bases de datos en diferentes ip en la misma sentencia.

Comment: Probablemente tendrás que enlazar los servidores, dado que las bases de datos se encuentran en diferentes IP, o sea, que están en diferentes servidores. Consulta [está pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1144051/5587982), las respuestas allí dadas y los enlaces.

Comment: Mi problema es que esta en un hosting compartido entonces no puedo agregar links server, solo agregar ODBC, pero no se como establecer la conexion en el php para hacer la consultas.

Comment: Si no puedes implementar Linked Server por cuestiones de permisos, la única solución que veo es consultar cada servidor individual y luego unir los resultados mediante código PHP o tratar de hacer la consulta conjunta desde una SP en SQL Server (una posibilidad a explorar, no estoy seguro de que funcione ni cómo se haría, quizá algún experto en SQL Server pueda aclarar ese punto).